# applescript: commands to maximize (green button) an iTerm window

Tags: terminal, applescript, iterm

Assuming I am opening an iTerm window with the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "iTerm"
            set win1 to (create window with default profile)
        repeat until exists win1
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        tell current session of current tab of current window
            write text "watch -n1 " & "'"  & "kubectl get pods | grep -i " & input & "'"
            split horizontally with default profile
            split vertically with default profile
        end tell
```

What code snippet should I use so that `win1` gets maximized (as in clicking on the green window button)?

**edit**: regarding the proposed solution indicated in the question that is supposed to be duplicate, I have changed my snippet as follows:

```
    tell application "iTerm"
            set win1 to (create window with default profile)
        repeat until exists win1
            delay 0.01
        end repeat
        tell application "System Events"
            perform action "AXZoomWindow" of (first button whose subrole is "AXFullScreenButton") of (first window whose subrole is "AXStandardWindow") of (first process whose frontmost is true)
        end tell
        tell current session of current tab of current window
            write text "watch -n1 " & "'"  & "kubectl get pods | grep -i " & input & "'"
            split horizontally with default profile
            split vertically with default profile
        end tell
```

However this now opens a new terminal window and no further command executes.

Comment: see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175410/applescript-to-click-green-zoom-button-with-option-down

Comment: The proposed solution does not work, I have edited my initial question to indicate this

Comment: When requesting help involving _code_, please provide proper samples. Your _code_ does not compile and `input` is not defined. **We can not test incomplete code!** That said, the `perform action` _command_ is going to go the the _frontmost_ window that meets the criteria of the the given _command_. As such, you need to use the `activate` _command_ after `tell application "iTerm"` so `win1` will be _frontmost_ when the `perform action` _command_ is triggered.

Comment: I don’t know the answer, but if I was looking for iTerm help, the place I’d go is the excellent Google Group where lots of helpful users hang out, as well as the developer <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/iterm2-discuss>.

Answer (score 1):

The `perform action` *command* is going to go the the *frontmost* window that meets the criteria of the the given *command*. As such, you need to use the `activate` *command* after `tell application "iTerm"` so `win1` will be *frontmost* when the `perform action` *command* is triggered.

```
tell application "iTerm"
        activate
        set win1 to (create window with default profile)
    repeat until exists win1
        delay 0.01
    end repeat
    tell application "System Events"
        perform action "AXZoomWindow" of (first button whose subrole is "AXFullScreenButton") of (first window whose subrole is "AXStandardWindow") of (first process whose frontmost is true)
    end tell
...
```